# Django - how to save distinct values in a queryset object?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following Django models: A Proposal which must be unique and Domains that could have the same name in separate Proposals but must be unique to the Proposal object that it belongs to.

```
class Proposal(models.Model):
   proposal_name = models.CharField(
      max_length=200,
      primary_key=True,
   )

class Category(models.Model):
   proposal_name = models.ForeignKey(
      Proposal,
      on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   )
   category_name = models.CharField(
      max_length=200,
      unique=True,
   )
```

**Currently if I have a Proposal -> Proposal 1, then it could contain Categories-> 'cat A', 'cat B'.
But If I have another Proposal -> Proposal 2, then I want this proposal to be able to contain similar category names like 'cat A'..**

But since in my Category model, I have given a **constraint of unique=True** to he category_name, I am unable to store such duplicate category names in a separate proposal.

Please guide an alternative for the same, probably a onetoonefield?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `unique` constraint from `category_name` field and unique together `proposal_name`, `category_name` fields to have a combined primary key.

```
class Category(models.Model):
   proposal_name = models.ForeignKey(
      Proposal,
      on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   )
   category_name = models.CharField(
      max_length=200,
      unique=True,
   )

   class Meta:
       unique_together = ('proposal_name', 'category_name',)
```

Comment: Yes 'unique_together' is such a simple and elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Django 2.2 you can use `UniqueConstraint` instead of `unique_together` like this:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['proposal_name', 'category_name'], name='give_it_some_name')
    ]
```

As the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) state:

> Use UniqueConstraint with the constraints option instead.
>
> UniqueConstraint provides more functionality than unique_together. unique_together may be deprecated in the future.